# Save specific weights in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

In my neural network, I create some `tf.Variable` objects as follows:

```
weights = {
    'wc1_0': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 3, 64])),
    'wc1_1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 3, 64]))
}
biases = {
    'bc1_0': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[64])),
    'bc1_1': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[64]))
}
```

How would I save the variables in `weights` and `biases` after a  specific number of iterations without saving  other variables?

Comment: There are quite a few different ways of doing it. You can use a tensorflow saver or use your favorite format like h5 or npy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard way to save variables in TensorFlow is to use a [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver) object. By default it saves all of the variables in your problem (i.e., the results of [`tf.all_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#all_variables)), but you can save variables selectively by passing the `var_list` optional argument to the `tf.train.Saver` constructor:

```
weights = {
    'wc1_0': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 3, 64])),
    'wc1_1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 3, 64]))
}
biases = {
    'bc1_0': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[64])),
    'bc1_1': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[64]))
}

# Define savers for explicit subsets of the variables.
weights_saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=weights)
biases_saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=biases)

# ...
# You need a TensorFlow Session to save variables.
sess = tf.Session()
# ...

# ...then call the following methods as appropriate:
weights_saver.save(sess)  # Save the current value of the weights.
biases_saver.save(sess)   # Save the current value of the biases.
```

---

Note that if you pass a dictionary to the `tf.train.Saver` constructor (such as the `weights` and/or `biases` dictionaries from your question), TensorFlow will use the dictionary key (e.g. `'wc1_0'`) as the **name** for the corresponding variable in any checkpoint files it creates or consumes.

By default, or if you pass a list of `tf.Variable` objects to the constructor, TensorFlow will use the `tf.Variable.name` property instead.

Passing a dictionary gives you the ability to share checkpoints between models that give different `Variable.name` properties to each variable.
This detail is only important if you want to use the created checkpoints with another model.